# Kaldor's Theory of Income Distribution

Tags: macroeconomics

I am referring to Kaldor/Keynesian theory of income distribution and I am having trouble understanding why the model won't work if marginal propensity to save of workers (S(w)) is more than the marginal propensity to save of profiteers (S(p)).

Specifically, I think my issue is not following what happens to investment and prices if S(w) > S(p).

Any thoughts will be helpful. Thanks